# Redirecting issues with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I have a login script, and when the login is successful I want it to redirect them to the home page(welcome_message.php) for some reason it does not link me to this file, instead throws a 404 and says `"The requested URL "http://localhost/musiclear/index.php/views/welcome_message" cannot be found or is not available. Please check the spelling or try again later."`

I am using CodeIgniters redirect() function for the change.

```
function validate_credentials() {

    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

    if ($query) { // if users credentials validated
        $data = array('usernames' => $this->input->post('username'), 
        'is_logged_in' => true);

        $this->session->set_userdata($data); //set session data
        redirect('welcome_message'); //redirect to home page
    } else { //incorrect username or password
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a tip but you should really (if you can) set up your .htaccess file to route requests through index.php so you can remove it from your urls. It makes them look horrible!

Comment: How can I do that? Im new to phgp

Comment: See here https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html and look for "Removing the index.php file". It's pretty simple even if you don't know anything about htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the full URI to the redirect function like so:

```
redirect(base_url('views/welcome_message'));
```

Assuming of course that your controller is `Views` and page (function) is `welcome_message`

Comment: Did this and it still did not work, still threw the same message

Comment: Do you have a controller set up in the application/controllers directory?

Comment: My controller is called welcome.php, it has the function home() in it which changes view to welcome_message

Comment: In that case, you must use redirect(base_url('welcome/home'));

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect browser to `view` file directly, but You can redirect it to `controller`, which will show Your view. In Your example You're trying to access CodeIgniter's (which based in `musiclear` folder on Your localhost) `Controller` with name `views` and call `welcome_message()` method from it. But if Your **really** want to show it You must have next structure:

```
  musiclear/
       Application
            Controllers
                   views.php
```

and `views.php` content:

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Views extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {
        // default action, required method
    }

    function welcome_message(){
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually when you make redirects in CodeIgniters it looks up for your controller and you should load view through the function of controller. e.g:

```
 function validate_credentials() {

        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

        if ($query) { // if users credentials validated
            $data = array('usernames' => $this->input->post('username'), 
            'is_logged_in' => true);

            $this->session->set_userdata($data); //set session data
            redirect(base_url().'home/welcome'); //redirect to home function
        } else { //incorrect username or password
            $this->index();
        }
    }

    function welcome(){
   $this->load->view('welcome_mesage');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot that `redirect()` function work only for controller class ie.
let you have `welcome`class so you can redirect it by using

```
redirect('wolcome');
```

you also redirect a function of controller class

if you want to redirect to `page` function of `welcome` controller class so you will writr

```
redirect('welcome/page');
```